# Stop floated div from snapping when another element is deleted

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

I'm *very* new to JavaScript, so apologies if this is a stupid question.

I want to make a scrolling ticker-style element. I looked up Mootools and using its FX.Transitions I can get Div elements to slide along nicely.

It works by having a div, 710px wide, centered in the screen, which I'll call the Viewport. Inside this div is another one, much wider, with sub divs all floated to the left. When the user clicks the next button, I set the css `left` property to `-710px` for the currently viewed item and the next one, using mootools to nicely slide them across. So:

- Left position: Invisible, the old slide which user has looked at and clicked next
- Center position: What's displayed on the screen at the moment
- Right position: Invisible, next slide for the user

The user sees the old element slide out and the new one slide in. All this works great.

However, on the next click, I'd like to delete the old slide which the user has already seen (but is invisible at the moment). I looked up how to do this in JavaScript, and it works fine. But the moment I delete it, the current center element snaps over to the left (instead of sliding), because it got `left: -710px` to bring it to the center, and has `float: left`!

I can fix this by setting `left: 0px` after the delete, which puts it back in the centre where it belongs, but I'm worried that on a slow browser, users will see the flicker of the element snapping to the left, and then reappearing as I correct for it.

I hope that made sense - if not, I can upload the code somewhere.

Is there a way I can delete the old, left-most element and prevent the other elements from moving? Like, for example, a way I can tell the browser "Don't redraw for a moment, please"? Or am I asking a stupid question and the time between the delete and the correction will be too fast for a user to ever notice a flicker? Or is there a smarter way to layout the elements?

Thanks!

Edit: Example of this here: jsfiddle.net/Az5Lg

Comment: go to www.jsfiddle.net and create an example with 2-3 slides, i'd be happy to take a look then. post ONLY js in the js bit, html in html and css at top, you can embed external css etc but images need to have a fully qualified domain name.

Comment: Hi Dimitar, I just added a link to the original post - cheers

Comment: A jsfiddle demo of the original code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Az5Lg/ (feel free to edit it into teh question if you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if you are doing the position change at the same time as the element removal (ie no calculations and other code between the two statements) then I would expect it to be too fast to be noticeable though you can always test to find out.

If you did want to avoid this you would have to do some kinds of gradual changing instead. I don't know what mootools does in terms of animations (http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Tween looks like what you want but I don't use mootools - I assume you are using this or similar to do your animaton already though) but if you could get it to animate the width of the div being removed to 0 instead of sliding the whole lot along (so left remains 0 but as you reduce the size of the current viewable element the new one slides into view).

You'd have to make sure you do the overflow of the "slides" properly to make sure content doesn't get squashed and appear wrong while it is disappearing but this should work (if it is possible with mootools which I imagine it would be).

Then of course once it is a zero width element you should be able to delete it with no impact on the page appearance.

**Edit to add workign example of a width transition:**

http://jsfiddle.net/A7YaW/ is a jsfiddle based on the page you linked with some different operations. The code is as similar as possible to yours to try to make sure you can see what it is doing.

The key things I've done are to create a Welcome0 box that is already off the left of the screen. I am slidiing the width of this down to 0 which in turn is causing all the other boxes which are floated left to slide up with it. Once the box is 0 width we can remove it in the next transition seemlessly.

The reason for the jump is related to your positioning. Roughly related to your positioning. You are positioning things relatively which means that their position is relaitve to the standard position it would be expected to be. When you are removing elements you are messing with this base position and thus juggling things around in a manner that confuses me a little still.

The advantage of using the width transition is that it only changes one element and is much simpler. Also you can probably take the element out the moment the transition has finished (I didn't look into how to do stuff on transition completion) which seems preferable to removing it on the next iteration.

**Edit with explanation of why the original wasn't working**

Since it was bugging me that I wasn't sure why the original was jumping I sat and worked out all the happenings and since I'd done that I thought I might as well share. And since its easiest I included ascii art diagrams to show how the various slides in the example are moving. Hopefully it all makes sense. :) The key thing is to do with how `position: relative` works so look that up if needed first. :)

```
  -----------------------------------------
  | Pos A | Pos B | Pos C | Pos D | Pos E |
  -----------------------------------------
-710      0      710     1420
```

In the above Pos B is your visible viewport.

When you first view the page your four slides (1 to 4) are in positions B, C, D and E respectively.

When you first transition you set the left position of your first two slides to -710. This moves them (and only them) to the left by that many.

Your slides are now in positions:

```
1 = A
2 = B
3 = D
4 = E
```

on the next run when you are deleting the first thing you do is to delete slide 1. At this point the "natural" layout of the page (ie before any repositioning styles) is with slides 2 to 4 in positions B to D. However, slide 2 has positioning on it to make it -710px relative moving it immediately to position A while 3 and 4 remain in positions C and D. You then apply the transition effect to slide 2 and 3. It has no effect on slide 2 (because it already has that style) and slide 3 slides into view as expected. It then repeats...

so diagramatically

```
Start:
  ----------------------------------------------
  |        | Slide1 | Slide2 | Slide3 | Slide4 |
  ----------------------------------------------

Click 1 - After transition
  ----------------------------------------------
  | slide1 | Slide2 |        | Slide3 | Slide4 |
  ----------------------------------------------


Click 2 - After delete
  ----------------------------------------------
  | slide2 |        | Slide3 | Slide4 |        |
  ----------------------------------------------

Click 2 - After transition
  ----------------------------------------------
  | slide2 | Slide3 |        | Slide4 |        |
  ----------------------------------------------


Click 3 - After Delete
  ----------------------------------------------
  | slide3 |        | Slide4 |        |        |
  ----------------------------------------------

Click 3 - After transition
  ----------------------------------------------
  | slide3 | Slide4 |        |        |        |
  ----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the suggestion. If I reduce the width of the box, won't it cut off the text on the right hand side as we "scroll/resize" out? I've done some initial tests in Firebug and it would seem so...

Comment: Most browsers will not redraw changes to the DOM that happen right next to each other.  They will only reconstruct the DOM tree.

Comment: Sorry, Josh, I'm not sure what that means. That there will be a single redraw?

Comment: @Frederik: you are right about that actually. In my original idea it would be like shrinking the visible div but you can achieve a similar effect by shrinking the width of the offscreen (to the left) div. I've included a link to a jsfiddle with a working example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Frederik: and yes, Josh is saying there will be a single redraw which is what I suspected but wasn't 100% sure of.

Comment: @Frederik: I've now also updated my answer to show why yours wasn't working in case you wanted to try to fix your own idea for making it work rather than changing your methodology.

Comment: Chris, that was the most amazing reply I've ever seen! Thank you! Do you take donations? :-)

Comment: @Frederik: If we ever meet you can buy me a drink. I don't take donations in any other form though. :) And that quality of answer is what happens when I get interested in a question and bored at work at the same time. :)